# What is the adjective for describing someone who has the same hobbies, interests, values as we do and someone who you can easily understand?

Tags: word-choice

What adjective would it be natural to use for describing someone who has similar interests, hobbies and values as we do? Can the word *close* be used in the sense? For example:

> Kate is very **close** to me.

I guess if I didn't need the adjective for expressing the idea, the noun *affinity* would be the way to go. AM I right? For example:

> I hava an **affinity** with Kate.

Comment: You could use ["carbon copy"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carbon-copy).

Comment: *Kindred spirit* is another noun phrase (hence not an adjective). *Alike* would do in many situations.

Comment: Or *Kate is very like me*. But it does depend on the precise context, particularly with *alike/like*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Kate is very close to me.

^ This does not express what you mean; it means that there is a strong emotional connection between the speaker and Kate or that the speaker feels strongly about her.

> I have an affinity with Kate.

^ This is closer to what you mean, but is less common use, and may leave the listener expecting you to explain or justify that statement.  If you just said that alone, the listener might wonder, "OK?  Well, what *is* that affinity exactly?"

One way many English speakers would express what you intend is:

> Kate and I are very much alike.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to describe Kate as someone who has "similar interests, hobbies and values" to me, I'd say "Kate and I [have a lot in common](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20a%20lot%20in%20common)." This is an idiomatic expression which tends to imply things like knowledge, beliefs, and attitudes rather than just physical attributes.